# Passing a function as a parameter - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In the BeautifulSoup documentation, a function has been defined as follow:

```
def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('id')
```

And then passed as a parameter to the function: `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all(has_class_but_no_id)
```

Which surprise me is that it worked. I really don't know how the mechanism is working here, how could this function(`has_class_but_no_id`) return a value for the `find_all()` function without having a parameter to work on?

Answer (score 1):

`has_class_but_no_id` is not executing when you pass it to `find_all()`.

`find_all` performs the call to `has_class_but_no_id`, multiple times, passing it tags as the value of 'tag' at that time. This is a pattern which takes advantage of the fact that in Python, functions are what's known as first-order objects - they exist as objects, and you can pass them around in variables.

This allows functions to accept other functions and run them at a later time - just like BeautifulSoup is doing here.

Try an experiment:

```
def say_something(something_to_say):
    print something_to_say

def call_another_function(func, argument):
    func(argument)

call_another_function(say_something, "hi there")
```

The above answer is taken from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3e0w9f/if_the_following_is_the_function_definition_then/).

Moreover, please see the [source code for find_all](https://github.com/newvem/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L766), and [call](https://github.com/newvem/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L594).

Comment: Extending this to explain what is happening in the example: find_all() is going over every tag in the page. For each, it's passing it as an argument to the function (as above). Where that function returns True, that is added to the final list of tags that are output. You can test that functionality by doing find_all(True) for a list of all tags.